# Why is android.R.menu_search giving me an error?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I'm trying to add a search widget to the action bar and for some reason I'm getting "android.R.menu_search cannot be resolved or is not a field". The code I'm using is

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.geolocation_search, menu);

        //Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(android.R.layout.menu_search).getActionView();
        //Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        //searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        return true;
    }
```

The xml file is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/headers"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/header1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/search"/>

</menu>
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own menu xml you can't read android's identifiers but yours.
So your issue will be resolved replacing

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(android.R.layout.menu_search).getActionView();
```

with

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
```